# copy created pie chart and calculated values to csv file

Tags: python

I almost completed my project but need some help. Let me summarize what I have already done. I exported a CSV file from ESXI, and using Python, I make several calculations and created a pie chart of these values. Here I have one result for calculation and the pie chart. Currently, I want to write these results to CSV simultaneously. How can I do that? As you know, pandas only display pie charts on different windows. I want to save that chart on CSV.

Answer (score 1):

A pie chart is just a type of data visualization. I guess you are already using a dataframe to display this using `plt.show()`.if you want to save that chart,
you could combine data,labels,colors to dataframe and save it as a csv. In order to save as csv: `df.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t')`